# How to read encrypted files (encfs)

Tags: encryption, fuse

lately, I installed encfs for encryption. and I encrypted files.
as far as I know, there are two directories. first directory is encrypted files stored and second directory is unencrypted files stored (It's original files).
I think the purpose of using encfs is reading or writing files safely using encrypted file(in first directory). I'm wrong..??
So my question is how to read encrypted files. the files are encrypted so I can't read or write files without decryption. How to decrypt files??
I think I don't know principle of encfs.. Anyone can explain this problem??

Answer (score 0):

How EncFS works is well explained here: http://ninjatips.com/encrypt-dropbox-using-encfs/

> EncFS uses two directories in mounting an EncFS filesystem: the
>   “rootdir” and the “mountPoint”. Under the “rootdir” directory, every
>   file is encrypted including its filename and what’s in it. Each file
>   in the “mountPoint” has a specific file in the “rootdir” directory
>   that corresponds to it. The file in the “mountPoint” provides the
>   unencrypted view of the one in the “rootdir” directory

When you mount an EncFS drive, it creates a virtual encrypted filesystem on your computer and stores encrypted data in the rootdir directory and makes the unencrypted data visible at the mountPoint. You add, read, delete... files in the mountPoint. The actual encrypted files are in "rootdir".